# Select count com union

Tags: mysql

Olá. Preciso fazer uma consulta mysql com 3 count na mesma tabela. Consegui que meus resultados aparecessem um em baixo do outro, na mesma coluna, porém preciso que fiquem em colunas diferentes.

É assim: preciso mostrar a quantidade de alunos matriculados nas aulas de ballet, a quantidade de alunos matriculados nas aulas de jazz e a quantidade de alunos que estão matriculados nas duas aulas. Desde o inicio do ano até hoje (04/09).

Minha query:

```
select count(*) as quantidade_ballet from alunos 
where datamatricula>='2015-01-01%' and datamatricula<='2015-09-04%'
and (indballet=1 and indjazz=0)

union(select count(*) as quantidade_jazz from alunos
where datamatricula>='2015-01-01%' and datamatricula<='2015-09-04%'
and (indjazz=1 and indballet=0))

union(select count(*) as quantidade from alunos
where datamatricula>='2015-01-01%' and datamatricula<='2015-09-04%'
and (indjazz=1 and indballet=1));
```

PS: indballet e indjazz são os indicadores booleanos de qual aula o aluno está matriulado.

Alguem pode me ajudar ? Obrigada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
count(*) as quantidade_ballet,
(select count(*) from alunos
    where datamatricula>='2015-01-01%' and datamatricula<='2015-09-04%'
    and (indjazz=1 and indballet=0)) as quantidade_jazz,

 (select count(*) from alunos
    where datamatricula>='2015-01-01%' and datamatricula<='2015-09-04%'
    and (indjazz=1 and indballet=1)) as quantidade

     from alunos 
    where datamatricula>='2015-01-01%' and datamatricula<='2015-09-04%'
    and (indballet=1 and indjazz=0);
```

para melhorar o desempenho use count(id) ao inves de count(*)

Comment: Beleza @Guerra, funcionou! Obrigada!!!

Comment: Disponha @Donnathegirl